# Why are partition and data recovery utilities saying my 2TB external hard drive is FAT16?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, filesystems, data-recovery, partition-recovery

I accidentally ran...

```
diskpart
format override /fs=ntfs
```

...on my 2TB external hard-drive. This only lasted for a few seconds before I stopped it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but was enough to make the drive unavailable to Explorer.

So far I've scanned the drive in testdisk, GetDataBack Simple and GetDataBack NTFS versions, all of which reported that the drive's file system is FAT16, while Recuva reported that it was unable to determine what file system it was.

The drive is a 2TB external drive that I'm pretty sure was NTFS before the damage, so is there a known, particular reason that the drive would appear to the above programs as FAT16? Should I continue treating it as a FAT16 drive in `testdisk` or should I attempt to restore it back to an NTFS file system?

Thanks, would really appreciate the help.

Comment: You could use my software (RecuperaBit). Given that it *only* supports NTFS there is no chance the file system would be confused with something else. :D We've already talked about it on Super User in the past.

Answer (score 2):

I've recovered data from broken striped raid arrays. The only thing I can think of that might be harder is broken parity raid arrays like raid 5 and 6. Regardless of what anyone tells you if the format only ran for a few moments, the majority of your data is still there.

The reason your external drive is showing as Fat is likely because it actually is and was Fat. The vast majority of external drives do not use NTFS because NTFS is not well supported apart from Windows NT and its successors (Windows 2000/Windows XP and newer). That said, they typically use Fat32 or exFat (a modernized variant specifically designed for external storage), not Fat16. However, if the original Fat32/exFat tables are corrupted it's possible for the file system to be misidentified.

Being that it's 2TB of storage your biggest problem will be if much of that was <strike>in use</strike> **ever** in use (deleted files count). You need to recover to a separate hard drive, not the same one. If you can do that you can run the recovery with any arbitrary filesystem selected without risk of further harming the data. If selecting Fat32 or exFat doesn't produce files you can read, there would be nothing stopping you from trying NTFS instead (except time, data recovery is laboriously slow, especially with externals).

It's been a while, but I remember GetDataBack allowing you to force any file system you want for the recovery attempt. If it doesn't you should try Active@'s Partition Recovery & File Recovery which can recover files even when the file system *and* partition parameters have been lost. It's what replaced GetDataBack for me and I've not regretted it. I also know for a fact it allows you to select arbitrary file systems formats for the recovery... but it also will show a list of possibly detected partition and file system parameters and grade them as to how likely it thinks they are to be the correct match based on how well a given match appears to align with and produce usable files.... letting you select the one you want to make the attempt with.

Just remember, as long as you keep the original hard drive mounted read-only and unchanged (or not mounted at all, since Active@ and GetDataBack don't need a mounted fs) you can make as many attempts with as many different parameters as you want till it starts spitting out files.

Comment: "Windows NT" is commonly understood to mean "Windows NT3.1 - NT4, Windows 2000, and every Windows PC OS since Windows XP". And I didn't say they all come formatted Fat32... I also pointed out exFat which, yes, is more common over the last several years. And Fat32 _does_ support volume sizes up to 2TB. If you have a question, ask. If you think I'm wrong, explain. But questioning my credibility when you're unfamiliar with the subject matter is going quite a bit too far.

Comment: "My observation of not recently seeing many external drives factory-formatted with FAT32 was (perhaps an unhelpfully-obscure) suggestion that it's becoming less typical for drives to use this format. I did not say it's not possible, nor impossible." Please actually read what I've written. Fat32 is not the only file system format I mentioned. I've pointed this out repeatedly now. I have never claimed that Fat32 is the only filesystem used on portable drives. Nor did I claim that it is the most common in recent years. In fact, I spelled out in my last comment that exFat is the most common today.

Comment: "A) there's a generation of Windows OSes that succeeded NT," Succeeded? Yes. Windows 2000. Windows XP. Windows Vista. Windows 7. Windows 8. And Windows 10... all built on the technology introduced by Windows NT. "B) which don't well support NTFS." No, I didn't say anything that suggested the __successors__ to Windows NT don't support NTFS. I was referring to *nix and mac which, until the introduction of the ntfg3g user mode fs driver in 2007 (over a decade and a half after NTFS was introduced), was dangerous to access NTFS from. Even today ntfs3g leaves much to be desired.

Comment: Please edit your answer accordingly. It's not clear that you're not talking about Windows OSes  when you use the phrase "beyond" Windows NT.

Comment: Edit made. [For the record](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+beyond). Definitions 5 and 1.

Comment: Thanks for the informed answer, @CliffArmstrong. I'm not sure why experienced users are making claims that all the data on a drive is gone the moment a format is initiated/interrupted, a claim that's both ignorant and irresponsible. It's lucky that I've always known that's not how drives work. To clarify what you're saying above, I believe you're suggesting that I should try to force an exFAT file system first, and if that doesn't work, then FAT32?

Comment: Essentially, yes. The most important thing is to do your level best not to make any modifications to the original hard drive. If you can accomplish that then you can keep attempting and re-attempting to recover the data as many times with as many settings as you have the patience for. Forcing exFat would be my first guess unless you're certain it was NTFS (say because you formatted it that way yourself, or it's a rare exception to the rule, etc). The key is to not let any modifications happen to the original drive until you confirm success.

Comment: In other words, don't try to recover in place. Recover the data to a different hard drive... confirm the recovery worked... and only then copy the recovered data back to the original.